# Factory pattern in F# for a web scraper

Tags: f#, web-scraping, factory-method

I'm trying to learn F# by creating a little web scraper that will do custom scraping based on the url domain. For this, I need to create and select the correct kind of scraper. I figure I would use a Factory that would determine the correct kind of scraper for me.

So here is the interface for my scraper

```
type IExtractor = 

    /// determines if the extractor will work for the url
    /// returns true if the extrator can handle the url
    abstract member Suitable : string -> bool

    /// name of the extractor
    abstract ExtractorName : string with get
```

Here is the instance of one of the scrapers

```
type CustomExtractor1() =

    /// <summary>
    /// tests whether the input url is valid
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url"></param>
    let (|ValidUrl|_|) url = 
        let regexExpression = "^http(s)?://www\.customsite\.com.*\?fd="
        // regex helper that returns string option
        Common.UrlMatch regexExpression url 

    interface IExtractor with 
        member this.Suitable url =
            match url with
            | ValidUrl url -> true
            | _ -> false

        member this.ExtractorName with get() = "Custom extractor"
```

Here is the Factory

```
module Extractor =

    let private _extractors: IExtractor list = [new CustomExtractor1(); new CustomExtractor2()]

    let create url = 
        let isSuitable (input: string) (ex:IExtractor)  = ex.Suitable input 
        let one (input:string) (ex:IExtractor) = true
        match (_extractors |> List.tryFind (isSuitable url) ) with
        | Some ex -> Some ex
        | _ -> None
```

Here is the usage

```
 let input = "https://www.customsite.com?fd=cWz5d"
            let extractor = Extractor.create input

            let extractorOption = 
                match Extractor.create input with
                | Some ex -> Some ex
                | _ ->
                     (
                     raise (Error ("no extractor found. Exiting"))
                     )

            let extractor = extractorOption.Value

            // do stuff with extractor  
            printfn "%s" extractor.ExtractorName
```

The flow for this usage somehow feels more like C#, so it seems a little off. Especially in the usage where I'm using `extractorOption.Value`. I am currently investigating using [ROP](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/) instead of exception handling for better control flow.

What do you think — is there a way to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining the `IExtractor` interface, wouldn't it be simpler with a function?

In this question, I assume that `ExtractorName` is a stand-in for something you'd *really* want the extractor to *do*, because otherwise, as the OP is stated, the extractor doesn't really do anything. In this case, an extractor is nothing by a `string`, but I assume that in reality, it'd be a *function*.

This would enable you to make the `Extractor` module simpler:

```
module Extractor =

    let private fooExtractor url =
        if url = "foo"
        then Some "Foo Extractor" // Stand-in for actual implementation
        else None
    let private barExtractor url =
        if url = "bar"
        then Some "Bar Extractor" // Stand-in for actual implementation
        else None

    let private extractors = [fooExtractor; barExtractor]

    let create url =
        extractors
        |> List.choose (fun candidate -> candidate url)
        |> List.tryHead
```

Each element of `extractors` is a *function* with the type `string -> string option`. In order to be useful, the return value should probably be another *function* that you can subsequently call; something like `string -> ('a -> 'b) option`.

Note the use of `List.choose` to pick only those functions that return `Some 'a`. Instead of the object-oriented Try/Parse pattern, you can indicate match success or failure with an option value.

Usage can be simplified as well:

```
let input = "https://www.customsite.com?fd=cWz5d"
match Extractor.create input with
| Some x ->
    // do stuff with extractor  
    printfn "%s" x
| None -> printfn "%s" "No extractor found; exiting."
```

Here, we're simply printing the name of the extractor, since `x` is a `string`, but if you imagine that `x` was instead a function, you'd be able to call it.

Comment: *hit enter too fast*
I like it! Yes, the ExtractorName was one of the operations an extractor can perform. In one case, I want to have a pretty name for the extractor to print out on console.

I don't need the interface to enforce a specific signature. The compiler will complain if the signature doesn't match.

Ultimately I was envisioning the extractor would have a couple of methods on it. If I wanted the extractor to have richer functionality, wouldn't making it a function limit how much I can extend it?